# an rdd char is to be converted into a dataframe

Tags: excel, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

The RDD data is to be converted into a data frame. But I am unable to do so. ToDf is not working,also I tried with array RDD to dataframe . Kindly advise me.This program is for parsing a sample excel using scala and spark

```
import java.io.{File, FileInputStream}
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.{XSSFSheet, XSSFWorkbook}
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType };
object excel 
  {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = 
  {
  val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Excel Parsing").setMaster("local[*]"))
  val file = new FileInputStream(new File("test.xlsx"))
  val wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file)
  val sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0)
  val rowIterator = sheet.iterator()
  val builder = StringBuilder.newBuilder
  var column = ""
  while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
  {
  val row = rowIterator.next();
  val cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
  while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
  {
  val cell = cellIterator.next();
  cell.getCellType match {
  case CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC ⇒builder.append(cell.getNumericCellValue + ",")
  case CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN ⇒ builder.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue + ",")
  case CELL_TYPE_STRING ⇒ builder.append(cell.getStringCellValue + ",")
  case CELL_TYPE_BLANK ⇒ builder.append(",")
  }
  }
  column = builder.toString()
  println(column)
  builder.setLength(0)
  }
  val data= sc.parallelize(column)
  println(data)
  }
  }
```

Comment: You are not doing anything with Spark in the code you have listed here...

Comment: Oh, I didn't see it there at the bottom. Anyway, @Shivansh Srivastava has already given you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For converting `Spark RDD` to `DataFrame` . You have to make a `sqlContext` or `sparkSession` according to the spark version and then use

```
val sqlContext=new SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._
```

Incase you are using **Spark 2.0** or above use SparkSession instead as SqlContext is deprecated in the new release !

```
val spark=SparkSession.builder.config(conf).getOrCreate.
import spark.implicits._
```

This will allow you to use toDF on RDD.
This might solve your problem !

Note: For using the sqlContext you have to inculde the **spark_sql** as dependency !

Comment: No you have to make the sqlcontext by yourself and SparkSession in case you are using Spark2.0